# How do i fix this seam on the neck?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

Found a Briar .obj and wanted to rig it. I am having this issue where after parenting to the rig, the neck and the head don't want to work as seen in the image. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that the head and body are separate meshes, however joining them (ctrl+j) yields no difference.[image: Briar neck seam1]

I imagine I would have to join the vertices, but I can't find a way too.

Comment: Your suspicion may be correct.  I often have problems with parenting several separate objects to an armature, when animation shows the jagged edges.   I have to *not only* join the objects, but also go through a tedious exercise (in edit mode) of creating new faces around the edges of the nearby meshes and doing "Vertex >> new Edge/face from Vertices".  You might be able to 1) Select Non-Manifold then 2) Mesh >> Merge by Distance, if lucky

Comment: @james_t After joining the head and the neck (ctrl+j) the vertices around the head and the neck are non manifold however they overlap onto each other. I was able to fix this by using merge by distance however i first had to increase the range of it from 0.00001 to 0.0001. This joined the vertices and fixed the seam.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of two meshes not being connect by vertices i.e. non-manifold.

1. (ctrl+J) this joins the two meshes into one.
2. Go into edit mode
3. (Select>>All By Attribute>> Non-Manifold) This selects all non-manifold geometry
4. Deselect unwanted geometry. This is easy if you go into wireframe mode and use (B+MMB) to deselect it.
5. Click M to open Merge Menu
6. select "Merge By Distance"

This should fix your problem if the vertices are close enough, however likely they are not and you will see "Removed 0 Vertice(s)". This can be fixed by opening the Merge Menu that appears at the bottom left. Simply increase the distance scale until  you see it remove more than 0 vertices

[image]

This should now have joined the non-manifold vertices and the mesh should now not have a seam in it.

[image]